# Linq .FirstOrDefault not working

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have a database where if the selected dvd's is not taken back (so the date of the arrival is empty) it should write to the linklabel that that the dvd is still rented:

```
var j = (from s in db.Rentals where s.MovieTitle == tb_movietitle.Text 
         select s.takenbackdate).FirstOrDefault();

if (j == null)
{
    linkLabel1.Text = "The dvd is still rented";
}
else
{
    linkLabel1.Text = "Rentable";
}
```

If I use `First()` it says that it is empty, but if I use `FirstOrDefault()` it shows `null` to all movies even if they have taken back date in the database.

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive. Are you sure, that `MovieTitle` and `tb_movietitle.Text` match exactly?

Comment: Are you sure you're only ever going to have at most one copy of each title available for rent?

Comment: the matches are exact,only 1 copy can be found in the database from a movie title

Comment: Link2SQL or entity framework?

Comment: Based on your usage here (regardless of the issue), I would use `Any()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` as they query will be faster (once it's working) as you won't be returning values from the database that you're otherwise throwing away/not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation talk about empty, they talk about the source, the list of elements. 
So if `FirstOrDefault` and `First` get a source that has no elements, the default value will be returned or an exception is thrown.

'Empty' does not refer to 'empty' values, like a null-value.

To get what you want, try this:

```
// Find the first DVD with the given title. If not found, an exception is thrown.
var j = (from s in db.Rentals where s.MovieTitle == tb_movietitle.Text).First();

// If the taken back date is null, it is still rented.
if (j.takenbackdate == null)
{
    linkLabel1.Text = "The dvd is still rented";
}
else
{
   linkLabel1.Text = "Rentable";
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help,the problem was that the textbox value was all time empty because the code run before the databindings would implement the movie title to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 var j = db.Rentals.Where(s=>s.MovieTitle.Contains(tb_movietitle.Text).Select(s=>s.takenbacktime ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i need to use the takenbacktime field from the database,if it is empty than the dvd is still rented,if it contains a date,it means they already bring back the dvd and it is available again :)

Comment: thank you for the help,the problem was that the textbox value was all time empty because the code run before the databindings would implement the movie title to the textbox